# Force ReplaceAll to output vector of same length

Tags: replacement

I would like to do a replace in an expression...

```
a = t;
b = 1;

a/.t->Range[1,5] (*returns: {1,2,3,4,5} *)
b/.t->Range[1,5] (*returns: 1           *)
```

but I would like to force the second output to return

```
{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
```

Is there a way I can do this? My expression for "b" will be changing so I thought it would be nice if I could just force it to do this (like map but for expressions).

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Edit to clarify what I am trying to do.

I have an expression of "t" that changes as I make calculations. For example, let the expression be

```
express = t^2; (* OR t, OR 1, OR 3*t+t^2 *)
```

I then would like to evaluate this expression at several values of t so I do the following.

```
tSet = Range[1,5]
express/.t->tSet
```

where I will get a list if the expression contains "t". If the expression is constant

```
express = 1;
express/.t->tSet (* will output just 1, I would like it to be list of ones of length 5 to match tSet *)
```

I just get the scalar value, 1.

I don't want to create a function that does this unless I absolutely have to.

Hope that makes more sense...

Comment: How comes `t`  has length 5? You asked for `same length as input`....

Comment: @belisarius Basically, I would like the expression to behave like a function without declaring a function. I would like "b/.t->Range[1,5]" to return "{1,1,1,1,1}" where I consider Range[1,5] to be an input vector of length 5. If that makes sense...

Comment: You seem to have your syntax backward.  `Range[1,5]` in your example is *output*, not *input*.  We need a more complete example of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: `express = t^2;t=Range@5;Print@expres;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your update I think this is the simplest way to achieve what I believe you want:

```
express = 1;
tSet = Range[1, 5];
Table[express, {t, tSet}]
```

> ```
> {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
> ```

```
express = t^2;
Table[express, {t, tSet}]
```

> ```
> {1, 4, 9, 16, 25}
> ```

You lose the direct vector evaluation of [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html) functions but this is both more general and a solution to your specific request.

---

Since you Accepted this (thanks) the result above must be what you want.  Here is a way to do it using [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) as you started with, instead of [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html).

When the right-hand-side of `/.` is a *list of lists of rules* the result is a list of substitutions each using one of those lists.  For example:

```
0 /. {{_ -> 1}, {_ -> 2}, {_ -> 3}}
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3}
> ```

Therefore you could achieve what you want by converting `t -> tSet` into a list of lists of rules:

```
new = List /@ Thread[t -> tSet]
```

> ```
> {{t -> 1}, {t -> 2}, {t -> 3}, {t -> 4}, {t -> 5}}
> ```

Application:

```
1 /. new
t^2 /. new
```

> ```
> {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
>
> {1, 4, 9, 16, 25}
> ```

There are other approaches but I think these two are the easiest to apply and the closest to what you requested.

Comment: If the OP accepts this one I'll upvote you as a recognition for your divination talent

Comment: @belisarius I have written more than once "+1 for divination" :^)

Comment: @belisarius Pay up. ;o)

Comment: OK,ok. But you're using [dangerous fumes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythia#Fumes_and_vapors). This is the last warning